# Application crash when i am using CFRelease

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to understand how should I use CFRelease. I think I don't use it right. The application crash when I am trying to release.

```
            if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")){
            //get phone numbers
            ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)person,kABPersonEmailProperty);
            for(CFIndex i=0;i<ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);++i) {
                CFStringRef mEmailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, i);
                CFStringRef mEmailTypeRef = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, i);
                NSString * type = (__bridge NSString*) mEmailTypeRef;
                NSString * email = (__bridge NSString*) mEmailRef;
                NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"!$_><"];
                type = [[type componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
                if (!email || [email length]==0 || !type || [type length]==0) {

                }else
                    [GlobalFunctions addValue:email andKey:CONTACT_EMAIL toGroup:type inArray:array];

                if (mEmailRef) {
                    CFRelease(mEmailRef);
                }
                if (mEmailTypeRef) {
                    CFRelease(mEmailTypeRef); // crash
                }
                if (emails) {
                    CFRelease(emails);
                }

            }


        }
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I found the problem, the email object was released in the for loop but create before.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: When ever you create a Core Foundation object or become the owner of it you would call CFRelease.

Comment: The problem I am not sure when i become the Owner of the Core Foundation object.if i follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203990/when-i-use-cfrelease so i need to release emails,mEmailRef,mEmailTypeRef right?

Comment: If the function name contains "Copy" or "Create", then you own the object, so you must release it when you finish your work with it. This is called "The Create Rule".

Comment: Their is a way to know for each object ( Core Foundation object ) what is the retain count of this object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will crash every time as you are releasing **emails** everyTime with in **for loop**.     Write this condition outside of for loop.

```
if (emails) {
   CFRelease(emails);
}
```

And I also want to know what error you are getting in console.

Comment: Yes but i am creating it in each loop. i try to get in out of the loop and release it in the end. didn't help.

Comment: If it still crashing then you can direclty assign label and value to NSString like:     // Get label
   NSString *rawLabel = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex((__bridge ABRecordRef)person, i);
   
   // Get value
   NSString *value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex((__bridge ABRecordRef)person, i);